# Manipular único registro de while

Tags: php, css, mysql

Considerando que estou desenvolvendo um pequeno ranking de classificação simples (foto), preciso de uma solução para pegar os 3 primeiros registros do select e aplicar uma formatação individual para eles, os demais sem necessidade.
Obs.: não desejo ter de utilizar 2 lops, uma maneira talvez seja utilizando arrays, correto?

[image: modelo]

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php 
        $selPlacares = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM jogadores j LEFT JOIN placares p ON p.pla_jog_id = j.jog_id GROUP BY j.jog_id ORDER BY p.pla_cartas DESC, p.pla_tempo ASC, j.jog_nome ASC");
        $selPlacares->execute();
        $cont = $selPlacares->rowCount(); ?>

        <table border="0" align="left" width="70" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr style="background: #58589E;">
            <td>Pos.</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="background: #E7BD40;">
            <td>1º</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="background: #c9c9c9; color: #000;">
            <td>2º</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="background: #623825;">
            <td>3º</td>
        </tr>

        <?php for($s = 4; $s <= $cont; $s++): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $s."&deg;"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endfor; ?>

        </table>

        <table border="0" align="left" width="85%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr style="background: #58589E;">   
            <td>Nome do jogador</td>
            <td>Quant. Cartas</td>
            <td>Tempo</td>
        </tr>

        <?php while($rowPlacares = $selPlacares->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rowPlacares->jog_nome; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowPlacares->pla_cartas; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rowPlacares->pla_tempo; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>


        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das formas mais indolores de se fazer isso com seu código atual é usando um contador dentro do `while` o qual você usaria como condição para aplicar alguma classe CSS, por exemplo.

```
<?php

$cursor = 0;

while($rowPlacares = $selPlacares->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):

$cursor++;

switch( $cursor ) {

    case 1: $trColor = 'red'; break;
    case 2: $trColor = 'green'; break;
    case 3: $trColor = 'blue'; break;
    case default: $trColor = 'black'; break;
}

?>

<tr style="background-color: "<?php echo $trColor; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $rowPlacares->jog_nome; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowPlacares->pla_cartas; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowPlacares->pla_tempo; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Não é lá muito elegante, mas você usou PDOStatement::fetch() ao invés de primeiro montar a estrutura com PDOStatement::fetchAll() e depois iterá-la, é uma saída.

Comment: Realmente desta maneira funciona, porém com CSS mais simples. Quando fiz a pergunta não necessariamente quis a resposta em PHP, porém, foi interessante conhecer a forma de resolver este problema. Vou utilizar CSS por ser mais simples, já conhecia a função deste código mas utilizava para intercalar linhas, não havia pensado nisto.  Obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Você tem duas formas de fazer isso via css, a mais simples é a seguinte:

### [Vide Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQRjd/)

```
table tr:nth-child(1){
background-color:#bbccaa
}
table tr:nth-child(2){
background-color:#aabbcc
}
table tr:nth-child(3){
background-color:#bbaacc
}
```

Dessa forma, a primeira linha da tabela vai ter o estilo aplicado em `table tr:nth-child(1)`, a segunda `table tr:nth-child(2)` e a terceira `table tr:nth-child(3)`

Comment: Realmente, bem mais prático, vou utilizar esta forma por ser mais prática, porém, o da primeira resposta exclareceu como podemos fazer utilizando PHP. Obrigado por sua resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer isso apenas com `CSS`, utilizando a propriedade [nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp), exemplo:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td{background-color:blue;}
table tbody tr:nth-child(2) td{background-color:green;}
table tbody tr:nth-child(3) td{background-color:yellow;}
```

[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8vLV/)

Comment: Realmente com CSS é bem mais fácil. mas ele quis saber como fazer com PHP. Fazer o quê né?

Comment: Concordo, CSS é mais fácil e resolve os problemas. Necessariamente não quis saber em PHP só não lembrei desta função em CSS então achava que não havia como solucionar isto em CSS. Foi bom conhecer as maneiras, obrigado!

Comment: Não por isso :)